# About definition of continuity (Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset containing a neighborhood of $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: soft-question, definition

The following definition is in "Multivariable Mathematics" by Theodore Shifrin.

> **Definition** Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset containing a neighborhood of $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathbf{f}:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$. We say $\mathbf{f}$ is *continuous at* $\mathbf{a}$ if $$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}).$$

I wonder why the author didn't write as follows:

> **Definition 2** Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset containing  $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathbf{f}:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$. We say $\mathbf{f}$ is *continuous at* $\mathbf{a}$ if $$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}).$$

I think **Definition 2** is simpler.

Is there any difference between **Definition** and **Definition 2**?

Comment: Compare these two definitions for an open punctured disc $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0<x^2+y^2 <1\}$ and $a=(0,0)$. I think the first one is a good definition for the limit at a point if $f(a)$ is replaced by some $L\in\Bbb R^m$, but, the one you suggested, for the continuity -as it requires a function to be defined at a point.

Comment: Is $U$ taken to be the natural domain? If so, ignore my comment.

Comment: As stated, the two are equivalent. We know $U$ is open in either case. If $U$ contains $a$, then $U$ also contains a neighbourhood of $a$; namely, $U$. And if $U$ contains a neighbourhood of $a$, it clearly contains $a$ itself.

Comment: You’re right that it is redundant. But this was done to be parallel to the definition of limit at the beginning of the section.

Comment: @Invisible Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @TedShifrin Professor Shifrin, Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we restrict our definition to functions with open domains then both of them are equivalent and the second is simpler, hence better. However, if we'd like to consider the broader class of domains, the first definition can be applied only to the points from the interior of the domain, which is bad. On the other hand, the second definition can be problematic at the isolated points of the domain, since we can't say what this limit is. To overcome these problems and to do it in the most general case, we can define the continuity in the one of the following equivalent ways (expressed shortly).

The function $f\colon \Bbb R^n\supset D_f\to \Bbb R^m$ is continuous at $a\in D_f$ iff

- $a$ is an isolated point of the domain or - if $a$ is a limit point of the domain - the limit condition (as above) is satisfied.
- [Heine definition] $D_f\ni a_n\to a\implies f(a_n)\to f(a)$.
- [Cauchy definition] ($\varepsilon-\delta$).
- preimage of any open set in $\Bbb R^m$ is open in $D_f$.
- preimage of any closed set in $\Bbb R^m$ is closed in $D_f$.

Comment: Mateo, Thank you very much for your answer.